# List Comprehension for a List of dict of dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries of dictionaries

Here is a Sample (JSON form):

```
[
    {
        "lineID": 26, 
        "name": "A", 
        "stations": [
            {
                "name": "La Poya", 
                "sens1": 1617, 
                "sens2": 1624
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Charles Michels", 
                "sens1": 1598, 
                "sens2": 1597
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Fontaine - Hôtel de Ville - La Source", 
                "sens1": 1596, 
                "sens2": 1595
            } 
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "lineID": 27, 
        "name": "B", 
        "stations": [
            {
                "name": "Cité Internationale", 
                "sens1": 2148, 
                "sens2": 2147
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Palais de Justice", 
                "sens1": 2139, 
                "sens2": 2138
            } 
        ]
    }
]
```

I'd retrieve a list of all 2nd level dict value where the key is `name`. I already tried something from a [similar question I already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467700/list-of-values-for-a-key-in-list-of-list-of-dictionaries). But it doesn't work.

Any idea how to do this without writing multiple for loops.

Comment: `[b['name'] for b in a['stations'] for a in jsonobj]` ?

Comment: First idea would be to have valid JSON, just sayin'...

Comment: yeah, sorry for that, I updated it.

Comment: @markcial using your idea I came to this : `[d['name'] for lst in myJson for d in lst['stations']]` thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code work for me :

```
[d['name'] for lst in myJson for d in lst['stations']]
```

`myJson` is my  List of dict of dict.